# Как организовать продажу контента в приложении (используя данные пользователя)

Tags: java, android, playmarket

Есть приложение, которое делает расчеты и выводит информацию основанные на данных пользователя. Т.е. пользователь купивший приложение должен ввести свои данные и я (разработчик) должен проследить чтобы пользователь не изменял в дальнейшем введенные данные, т.е. привязать к его аккаунту.

И если он переустановит приложение, то эти данные автоматически бы загрузились к нему.

Если пользователь захочет ввести другие данные или дополнительные данные, то дать ему возможность после доплаты, т.е. продать возможность внести дополнительные данные.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Клиент-сервер хеш, ssl ?

Comment: Может у PlayMarket есть инструменты для этого?

Comment: У них однозначно есть инструменты для получения денег с вас .. за ваши деньги - любой каприз :) хуже только яблоко сторе..

Comment: Приложение и так на PlayMarket

Comment: Так у них там целая платформа сервисов, наверняка можно что то подобрать, но мое мнение, что этот путь будет связан с постоянными переделками под их меняющееся API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что вам поможет следующее:

- Использовать non-consumed one-time product specific purchase
  https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_onetime
- Для того чтобы пользователь мог зайти и использовать с другого устройства использовать https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#Keep-up-to-date getPurchase и смотреть приобретенние INAPP и по ним генерить доп. данные по purchase token купленных продуктов.